# Dynamic wsdl value for a jax ws web service client

Tags: java, web, groovy, service, jax-ws

Okay. So i'm taking over a very very old system that uses Groovy, and this application is connecting to a third party web service via its configuration file with the entry like this: (this is for prd)

```
webService.wsdlUrl = "jar:file:/lib/MyWebService.jar!/META-INF/wsdl/MyServices_live.wsdl"
```

It has its own set of groovy configuration files for qa and prd. Qa looks like this:

```
webService.wsdlUrl = "jar:file:/lib/MyWebService.jar!/META-INF/wsdl/MyServices_qa.wsdl"
```

These MyServices_live.wsdl and MyServices_qa.wsdl files contain the path to the actual web service url (for prd and qa respectively) which is the one that needs to be replaced for both instances.

I already have the new url. So what did I do? I don't have enough experience doing this so I had to do some research. Apparently, I can use "wsimport" to connect to the new web service url and append ?wsdl to the end of this url so I can generate a jax-rs web service client. I was able to produce a set of java codes that I eventually learned that theyI thought problem solved. I just need to compile these java codes and jar the classes, so I'll have an updated MyWebService.jar.

Now, I realized with what I have done, the wsdl parameter is embedded in the code

```
@WebServiceClient(name = "Services", targetNamespace = "http://blahblah/", wsdlLocation = "https://newhostname.com/Service?wsdl")
```

With this approach, I would create 2 jars, 1 for prd and 1 for qa which won't be the most ideal thing to do. We would like to retain the previous capability of controlling where the web service client (inside the jar)  will point to by using a parameter (e.g. just like here... the wsdl was specified jar:file:/lib/MyWebService.jar!/META-INF/wsdl/MyServices_live.wsdl ).

Again, to highlight the architecture, the application is running in Groovy and it is using a jar file to access some third party services.

I haven't really done any Groovy development, so I would like to as much as possible not touch any Groovy code.

Would you have any idea of how i can go about this problem?

Comment: The `wsdlLocation` parameter can take a local path, eg. `META-INF/wsdl/my.wsdl`. While this doesn't completely solve your problem, it would mean the jar only need to be repackaged, not recompiled, to change the wsdl.

Comment: @JureKolenko you mean to say i can use the original MyWebService.jar and just edit the necessary values (i.e. update the values that point to the new url) inside the wsdl and just repackaged the jar? I haven't tested that yet...

Comment: If only the _location_ of the wsdl is the problem, then repackaging would likely work (if it references a local copy), if the wsdl actually changed, then that wont work.